# how to use fadeTo and fadeIn properly here

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to fade out 1 div out of two joined divs but not able to do so.Please help me out

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
            $("#hide").fadeTo(slow, 0);
        }
        if($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
            $("#hide").fadeIn(slow, 0.7); 
        }
    });
});
```

and my html code for  divs which are are

```
<div id="logoin" style= "width:1348px;height:65px;background-color:Black;opacity:0.7;z-index:200"></div>
<div id="hide" style=" position:absolute;top:65px;width:1348px;height:15px;background-color:black;opacity:0.7"></div>
```

how to get the fade effect?

Comment: Can you describe your desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your `slow` speed should be `'slow'`, but I think that it's better do this simple animation with CSS transitions, it's very easy:

**CSS:**

```
#hide{
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 0){
            $("#hide").css('opacity', 0);
        }else{
            $("#hide").css('opacity', 0.7);
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/gxgjdhb1/

Comment: Because `fadeIn` don't take the `opacity` as argument, only a speed and callback. See here http://api.jquery.com/fadein/